# OrderBy in LINQ Expressions

Tags: c#, linq, expression

**First of all**, I want to filter out the answers that would suggest to make this whole thing in memory because that's the system I'm trying to replace (stating because I only saw those answers for questions like this one).
**Second of all**: ask away, I know I'm pretty bad at explaining stuff, I will edit the post accordingly.

My problem is that I have a big SQL database of InvoiceItems and would like to dynamically put a Query together (Filtering for different time intervals, statuses also do groupings, ordering and aggregations) with LINQ Lambda Expressions so that I only have to query once after the expression set is made.

I use LINQ on a custom database repo interface, they work like a charm:

```cs
ParameterExpression argParam = Expression.Parameter( typeof( InvoiceItem ), "invoiceitem" );

Expression whereExpression = Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Constant( context.TenantId ),
                Expression.Property( argParam, nameof( InvoiceItem.PartitionKey ) ) );
Expression timeintervalExpressionFrom = Expression.LessThanOrEqual( 
                Expression.Constant( resultTimeInterval.DateFrom ), 
                Expression.Property( argParam, nameof( InvoiceItem.IssuingDate ) ) );
whereExpression = Expression.AndAlso( whereExpression, timeintervalExpressionFrom );
Expression timeintervalExpressionTo = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(
                Expression.Constant( resultTimeInterval.DateTo ),
                Expression.Property( argParam, nameof( InvoiceItem.IssuingDate ) ) );
whereExpression = Expression.AndAlso( whereExpression, timeintervalExpressionTo );

var invoiceItems;
Expression<Func<InvoiceItem, bool>> whereExpressionFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<InvoiceItem, bool>>( whereExpression, new[] { argParam } );

using( InvoiceStatisticsModelsContext db = InvoiceStatisticsModelContext.GetSQLDatabase() as InvoiceStatisticsModelsContext ) {
    ISQLRowRepository<InvoiceItem> itemsRepo = db.InvoiceItems.CreateRepository();

    invoiceItems = itemsRepo
                .AsQueryable()
                .Where( whereExpressionFunc )
                .AsEnumerable()
                .ToList();
}
```

I want to strap a GroupBy and a OrderBy to this query as well, which should be something like:

```cs
invoiceItems = itemsRepo
            .AsQueryable()
            .Where( whereExpressionFunc )
            .GroupBy( groupBy )
            .AsEnumerable()
            .ToList();
```

Where **groupBy** could be:

- item => item.IssuingDate.Year
- item => item.IssuingDate.Month
- item => item.IssuingDate.Day
- item => item.PartnerId
- item => item.MaterialId

**So my question is**: how could I make GroupBy and OrderBy Expressions dynamically to only query everything once at the end.

Comment: have you tried https://dynamic-linq.net/ ?
There is Microsoft Documentation how to do `OrderBy`
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries
But what you have to do with `GroupBy`, this is the question.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv The problem is that I work for a company and the program is mostly done and I can't bring in new stuff (just a junior) but I'm asking here because nobody used Expressions in the company before and I am the one responsible for learning it.   
I want to make Expressions dynamically (the user might ask for a yearly, monthly, daily or by material/partner grouping) so that I can just shove my GroupBy Expression inside the query at the end of the task, like so:   
invoiceItems.AsQueryable().Where( whereExpressionFunc ).OrderBy( orderByFunc ).GroupBy( groupByFunc ).ToList()

Comment: Usually `GroupBy` has no sense without aggregation functions.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I know that, thank you but my question wasn't that. It was how how could I make the expressions into a variable.

Comment: I still did not get. Next time create question with code samples. LINQ query which you want to create dynamically. It is not so hard to do that.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I'm still editing the question, and I know it's not that hard but I'm still 'learning' what to include and how to do it. Wait a few minutes and I'll be done with the edit.

Comment: Generally, the *Predicate Builder* (and associated tools) is often the answer to building expressions dynamically.  I'm not sure if it would be a help here.  http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: @Flydog57 This one seems useful after glancing in it for a short minute.

Comment: @sens1tiv, create new question and delete this one, since it is already closed. Still not clear for me for which purpose you need groping. What you you have to do with grouped items in that way?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv It's not appropriate to delete and re-post the same question.  The appropriate thing to do is to edit the question such that it merits being reopened.

Comment: @Servy, so question is edited and not reopened. What to do?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Then it doesn't *merit* being reopened, and it needs to continue to be improved until it does.  Or you just need to be patient and give it a bit of time to get reopened, if it has not been long enough for people to have a chance to reopen it.

Comment: Who closed question and who should reopen it?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv You can see that in the close message.  It can be reopened by anyone with the reopen privilege..

Comment: Are the types of your fields in your possible `GroupBy` keys the same? If not, then you have a problem since your `IGrouping` type will be determined at runtime, and that makes it hard to work with later.

Answer (score 1):

For OrderBy you have to do similar manipulations

```cs
...

invoiceItems = itemsRepo
                .AsQueryable()
                .Where( whereExpressionFunc );

var orderByPropName = "some";

var orderLambda = Expression.Lambda(
   Expression.Property(argParam, orderByPropName), argParam);

var orderByCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), 
   "OrderBy", 
   new [] { argParam.Type }, 
   invoiceItems.Expression, orderLambda);

invoiceItems = invoiceItems.Provider.CreateQuery<InvoiceItem>(orderByCall);
```